# React Router V6 NavLink doesn't show active

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

Trying to replace some old methods with NavLink and react-router but my code doesn't seem to work

```
   return (
      <div className='Selection-container'>
      <div className="Selections">
      <NavLink to="/best">
       <button  className='Best' value='best' onClick={handleSelection}>Best</button>
       </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/hot" >
       <button  className='Hot' value='top' onClick={handleSelection}>Hot</button>
       </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/new" >
       <button   className='New' value='new' onClick={handleSelection}>New</button>
       </NavLink>
      </div>
        {loading && <div className='Loading-main' ><img src={loadingImg} alt='loading' className='Main-loading' /></div>}
     
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/best' element={<PostMain />} />
        <Route path='/hot' element={<PostMain />} />
        <Route path='/new'  element={<PostMain />}/>
      </Routes>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to render different kind of post inside  the buttons seem to work they change the content in the page the change the route in the browser just the "active" button is not active when i'm on Best-Hot or New pages (at the end i wanna display active:inactive images in css as background but for now i would settle with anything that shows the current active page ).

Comment: By default, an `active` class is added to a `<NavLink>` component when it is active. One difference as of v6 is that `activeClassName` and `activeStyle` have been removed from `NavLinkProps`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show as "active" in the code snippet you've provided? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i understand the problem, here's an example of what you need

```
<NavLink style={({ isActive }) => isActive ? {backgroundImage:'yourimg'} : {}} 
        ...
</NavLink>
```

You can use className insted of style

```
<NavLink className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'activeBtn' : ''} 
        ...
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Thank you! it's working this way ,but if i style the background it changes behind the button element , and if i wanna change textcolor that doesnt even show and also if i set the background image like this "{backgroundImage:`url('/src/img/bestActive.png')`}" that still doesnt change (i have "backtick") before and after the url i dont know why it doesnt show it in this comment text

Comment: In your css you can do something like this like this `.activeBtn button{...}` or .`activeBtn .btnClass{...}`

Comment: i figured it out Thx the specification was the same on the old and the active style so it was always shown behind the old image now i set the active img a more specific selector and it works! big ups!!

Comment: I thought you had another class besides .active to use that's why i recommend the {isActive} way, i will update the answer. and about the styling problem im not quite sure about your problem update your question or just try to make clear a bit here

Answer (score 1):

yes in v6 a few have changed, "end" works as "exact" and "strict" before

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
<li>
  <NavLink end to="/">
    HOME
  </NavLink>
</li>
```

you can style the active link with the selector:

```
[aria-current="page"] {
    background-color: purple;
}
```